# Problems running Processing P2D and P3D in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, opengl, processing, jogl

I’d like to run Processing in an old computer (Acer ES1) with Xubuntu , but while everything seems to work fine, when I run sketches that use P2D or P3D I get the following error:

`InternalError: XXX0 profile[2]: GL2 -> profileImpl GL3bc !!! not mapped`

This happens with Processing 4.1.1. (as well as 4.0 and 3.5.4). In my understandings the issues is about an old bug that has been solved in the recent version for most of the machines, but not for mine. I suppose the bug should be related to this:
[P3D don’t work on AMD dynamic switchable graphics #5308](https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/5308)

I tried to follow all the possible workarounds suggested in the previous link but nothing worked out. The only thing I didn’t try and that I would avoid is downgrading the version, since I need to work with the latests.

Comment: I'm the person who provided the patched class files. Rather use the very latest release candidate of JOGL 2.4. Contact JOGL contributors and maintainers on our official forum.